# TypeError: NoneType object not iterable

Tags: python, list, class, oop, iterable

It might be silly question but I just started to learn OOP in Python and I am struggling to get this one:

The following code works fine:

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=None

C1='Stephen Curry'
C2='Kevin Durant'
C3='LeBron James'
C4='Chris Paul'


nameList=[C1,C2,C3,C4]
nameList.sort()
for e in nameList:
    print (e)
```

However, when I use nameList.sort() inside the for loop, it gives me "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=None

C1='Stephen Curry'
C2='Kevin Durant'
C3='LeBron James'
C4='Chris Paul'

nameList=[C1,C2,C3,C4]

for e in nameList.sort():
    print (e)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` returns `None` because it sorts the list *in place*. If you want to iterate over a sorted list in one statement, you should use `sorted`:

```
for e in sorted(nameList):
    pass
```